# Neo4j SPARQL-plugin REST usage

Tags: java, neo4j, semantic-web

Im trying to run a SPARQL-query on my neo4j database by using the REST API. For getting a SPARQL-endpoint, Ive installed the Noe4j SPARQL-plugin (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/sparql-plugin). My system now exposes these sparql-endpoints:

```
http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/insert_quad
http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/execute_sparql
```

Im trying to use the sencond one to execute queries. The HTTP POST Request is supposed to be like "Example 2" in http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/sparql-plugin/ with a slightly easier query.
This is the source-code:

```
private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/execute_sparql";


private static String query = "SELECT ?x WHERE {?x ?y ?z} LIMIT 5";


public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(ENDPOINT);

    // Request parameters and other properties.
    httppost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Method", "POST"));
    httppost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));
    httppost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));

    JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
    holder.put("query", query);
    System.out.println(holder.toString());
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(holder.toString()));

    //Execute and get the response.
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    System.out.println("HEADER:");
    System.out.println("Status code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    Header[] hlist = response.getAllHeaders();
    for (int i = 0; i < hlist.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(hlist[i].getName() + " ");
        System.out.println(hlist[i].getValue());
    }
    System.out.println("-----");
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("x " + line);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Entity is null");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I dont get the desired output. The output is:

```
{"query":"SELECT ?x WHERE {?x ?y ?z} LIMIT 5"}
HEADER:
Status code : 200
Content-Length 4
Content-Type application/json; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Server Jetty(6.1.25)
-----
x null
```

I´m pretty sure that this SPARQL query is correct; I also didnt notice any problems upon installing the sparqpl-plugin, so I have no idea why I get "null" as result. Ive tried looking for a solution via google, but I didnt find anything helpful. How can I fix this ?
Im using the **Community-Edition of Neo4j 1.9.2 running on Windows 7**
The version of the installed sparql plugin is "0.2 SNAPSHOT"
**EDIT 1:** If I run this query:

```
SELECT ?x WHERE {?x ?y ?z} LIMIT 0
```

The output is:

```
{"query":"SELECT ?x WHERE {?x ?y ?z} LIMIT 0"}
HEADER:
Status code : 200: OK
Content-Length 3
Content-Type application/json; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Server Jetty(6.1.25)
-----
x [ ]
```

Maybe this helps at finding the error.

I´ve also tried running queries from the HTTP Console of Neo4j:

```
http> POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/execute_sparql {"query":"select ?x where { graph ?g { ?x ?y ?z } }"}
==> 200 OK
==> null

http> POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/execute_sparql {"query":"select ?x where { ?x ?y ?z  }"}
==> 200 OK
==> null
```

**EDIT 2:**
I´ve tried to re-download and build the plugin. Afterwards I installed it, by unzipping it at NEO4J_HOME/plugins/sparql. Then, after I started Neo4j.bat, I executed my java-code. The following error came up at the console:

```
x {
x   "message" : "com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/neo4j/Neo4jGraph",
x   "exception" : "NoClassDefFoundError",
x   "fullname" : "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
x   "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.initSail(SPARQLPlugin.java:90)", "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.executeSPARQL(SPARQLPlugin.java:61)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:57)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:168)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:300)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:122)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)" ],
x   "cause" : {
x     "message" : "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph",
x     "exception" : "ClassNotFoundException",
x     "stacktrace" : [ "java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)", "java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)", "java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)", "java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)", "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)", "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)", "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.initSail(SPARQLPlugin.java:90)", "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.executeSPARQL(SPARQLPlugin.java:61)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:57)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:168)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:300)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:122)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)" ],
x     "fullname" : "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
x   }
x }
```

I´ve found, that "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph" is part of some "blueprints-neo4j-graph.jar". This jar-file was missing in my sparql/ folder, so I searched for the most recent jar file and added "blueprints-neo4j-graph-2.5.0-20130916.151744-5.jar". After restarting the server, the error doesnt come up anymore, but I still get "null" as result (at either of both queries)
**EDIT 3:** Ive also tried coying some parts of the "BerlinDatasetTest.java" from the github page of the neof4 sparql-plugin and running it manually (ofc after adding all necessary jar files). This is the source code:

```
public String runQuery(String raw_query) {
        String q_result = "";
        Sail sail = new GraphSail( new Neo4jGraph("my_db/") );
        try {
            sail.initialize();
            QueryParser parser = new SPARQLParserFactory().getParser();
            ParsedQuery query = null;
            CloseableIteration<? extends BindingSet, QueryEvaluationException> sparqlResults;

            SailConnection conn = sail.getConnection();

            query = parser.parseQuery(raw_query, "http://localhost:7474");
            sparqlResults = conn.evaluate( query.getTupleExpr(),


             query.getDataset(), new EmptyBindingSet(), false );

        while ( sparqlResults.hasNext() ) {
            q_result += "; " + sparqlResults.next();
        }

        conn.close();
        sail.shutDown();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return q_result;
}
```

This is the result I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.oupls.sail.GraphSailConnection.toSesame(GraphSailConnection.java:729)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.oupls.sail.GraphSailConnection.fillStatement(GraphSailConnection.java:636)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.oupls.sail.GraphSailConnection.access$800(GraphSailConnection.java:36)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.oupls.sail.GraphSailConnection$StableStatementIteration.next(GraphSailConnection.java:624)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.oupls.sail.GraphSailConnection$StableStatementIteration.next(GraphSailConnection.java:589)
    at info.aduna.iteration.IterationWrapper.next(IterationWrapper.java:71)
    at net.fortytwo.sesametools.QueryEvaluationIteration.next(QueryEvaluationIteration.java:45)
    at net.fortytwo.sesametools.QueryEvaluationIteration.next(QueryEvaluationIteration.java:16)
    at info.aduna.iteration.IterationWrapper.next(IterationWrapper.java:71)

    at info.aduna.iteration.FilterIteration.findNextElement(FilterIteration.java:69)
    at info.aduna.iteration.FilterIteration.hasNext(FilterIteration.java:43)
    at info.aduna.iteration.ConvertingIteration.hasNext(ConvertingIteration.java:62)
    at info.aduna.iteration.ConvertingIteration.hasNext(ConvertingIteration.java:62)
    at info.aduna.iteration.IterationWrapper.hasNext(IterationWrapper.java:57)
    at org.openrdf.sail.helpers.SailBaseIteration.hasNext(SailBaseIteration.java:50)
    at src.QueryTest.runQuery(QueryTest.java:113)
    at src.QueryTest.main(QueryTest.java:140)
```

"QueryTest.java" is the name of the java-class in which I run this function.

**EDIT 4:** It appears, that the result is only null, if

```
query.getDataset()
```

becomes null (which happens at both of the queries) If I add a FROM clause or start using URLs inside the WHERE-part, query.Dataset() isnt null anymore and Im getting an empty result (which isnt null). Those are two of the "working" queries:

```
select ?x from <localhost:7474> where { graph ?g { ?x ?y ?z } } 
select ?x where { graph ?g { ?x <http://localhost:7474#knows> ?z } }
```

I still dont get any results.

Comment: How many results do you actually expect to get back?  What happens if you use the query `select ?x where { graph ?g { ?x ?y ?z } }` so that you're searching over all named graphs, and not just the default graph?  (In some endpoints, the default graph is the union of the named graphs, but in others it's not.)

Comment: I´ve loaded a 2gb *.nt file into neo4j, so I expect to get many triples back; thatswhy I added "LIMIT 5". Unfortunately, the result doesnt change if I use your query.

Comment: Your query seems to be _running_ successfully (i.e., you're getting non-error results), so it does seem like the problem lies elsewhere.  Perhaps rather than running with a 2GB dataset, you can set up a minimal example a simpler configuration that might be easier to debug?

Comment: Something interesting happened.. this is what I did, on an empty database
* Created 2 nodes: Node1 and Node2 without adding properties to them
* Created 1 relationship: Node1 [RELATED_TO] Node2
* Executed my java program with your query
* Now, the database has another node, called Node3, with 1 property:
(Yes, the name of this property is value, and its value is "urn:com.tinkerpop. ..")
value : "urn:com.tinkerpop.blueprints.pgm.oupls.sail:namespaces"
The result of my java-code didnt change. It doesnt add another node if I run the java-code again

Comment: Can you execute the tests in the source code successfully?

Comment: The source-code from the test-class (see EDIT 3) didnt work either. Ive now tried to insert triples by using the insert_quad Endpoint of the sparql plugin. As an example, I´ve tried sending the "Figure 1" request of http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/sparql-plugin/ to an empty database. No error occured. I sent a query and got a the correct result (I guess I might have added the triples wrong in the first place)

Comment: Unfortunately, queries dont work if I just add nodes in the web-gui (without adding any properties) Is this an intended behaviour or did I do anything wrong? (I added the nodes as descirbed above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running 4 node cluster.
The fix for ClassNotFoundException is very simple.

1. The gremlin plugin folder you copy contains older version (1.2) of blueprints-core and blueprints-neo4j-graph. Delete those old libraries under the gremlin plugin directory.
2. Update pom.xml of sparql plugin project to include latest blueprint libraries. Trigger a maven build (mvn clean package). Now extract the neo4j-sparql-plugin-0.2-SNAPSHOT-server-plugin.zip into gremlin directory. Make sure you have latest blueprints-neo4j-graph-2.3.0.jar.

Try

Now your APIs should work and you can treat your Neo4j as a full fledged triplestore. Have fun!