# How to use REST endpoint to work with neo4j SPARQLPlugin

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to run "SPARQLPlugin" with the neo4j 2.0 M06, on a newly installed folder with no data in the database, but I am unable to find an example as to how I can call the REST endpoint. Is there an example somewhere that shows how the rest endpoint can be used play with SPARQL?

I am trying with the chrome Advanced rest client as shown below
[image: POST Call with the example data]

i get an error response as below:

```
{
  "message" : "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map",
  "exception" : "BadInputException",
  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.BadInputException",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.formats.JsonFormat.readMap(JsonFormat.java:92)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormat.readParameterList(RepresentationFormat.java:97)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:132)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)" ],
  "cause" : {
    "message" : "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map",
    "exception" : "ClassCastException",
    "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.JsonHelper.jsonToMap(JsonHelper.java:53)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.formats.JsonFormat.readMap(JsonFormat.java:88)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormat.readParameterList(RepresentationFormat.java:97)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:132)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)" ],
    "fullname" : "java.lang.ClassCastException"
  }
}
```

I have checked that the plugin is loaded in the neo4j and its also throwing error when i do something silly, so I assume that its working. So really looking forward to see how this can be used.

**EDIT:**

As suggested below here is the stack trace when I include the { } around my payload where I get **500** status back

```
    {
  "message" : "com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/neo4j/Neo4jGraph",
  "exception" : "NoClassDefFoundError",
  "fullname" : "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.initSail(SPARQLPlugin.java:90)", "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.executeInsert(SPARQLPlugin.java:113)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:168)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:132)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)" ],
  "cause" : {
    "message" : "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph",
    "exception" : "ClassNotFoundException",
    "stacktrace" : [ "java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)", "java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)", "java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)", "java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)", "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)", "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)", "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.initSail(SPARQLPlugin.java:90)", "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.executeInsert(SPARQLPlugin.java:113)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:168)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:132)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)" ],
    "fullname" : "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
  }
}
```

I didn't include this initially assuming this to be a mistake on how I am posting the data to the endpoint.

**EDIT 3**

I tried to build the plugin again (using "mvn package -DskipTests" as tests were failing) this time pointing it to 2.4.0 of blueprint in the plugin pom.xml and downloaded the correct version of missing blueprints-neo4j-graph-2.4.0.jar for blueprint. after that i see a new error, but looks like its getting closer this time, may be some version mismatch again. any idea what this is?

```
{
  "message" : "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getGraphProperties()Lorg/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/GraphProperties;",
  "exception" : "NoSuchMethodError",
  "fullname" : "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",
  "stacktrace" : [ "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.getInternalIndexKeys(Neo4jGraph.java:235)", "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.loadKeyIndices(Neo4jGraph.java:175)", "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:140)", "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:144)", "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.initSail(SPARQLPlugin.java:90)", "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.executeInsert(SPARQLPlugin.java:113)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:168)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:132)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)" ]
}
```

also the Query is returning a similar error:

```
{
  "message" : "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getGraphProperties()Lorg/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/GraphProperties;",
  "exception" : "NoSuchMethodError",
  "fullname" : "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",
  "stacktrace" : [ "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.getInternalIndexKeys(Neo4jGraph.java:235)", "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.loadKeyIndices(Neo4jGraph.java:175)", "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:140)", "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:144)", "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.initSail(SPARQLPlugin.java:90)", "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.executeSPARQL(SPARQLPlugin.java:61)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:168)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:132)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)" ]
}
```

Thanks, Kiran

Comment: Shouldn't your payload be a map/json-object, i.e. add curly braces around it?

Comment: @MichaelHunger : Actually the edit i made refers to the exception I get when I add curly braces around the payload. I am certain that I am missing something very basic but can't figure out what!. BTW I am just trying out the example at the following [Link](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/sparql-plugin/)

Comment: Hey, did you manage to find a solution for the last issue (edit 3)? I'm kinda stuck on the same thing...

Comment: @dafmetal : Well not really, but I moved back to 1.9.2 where it works. just had to fix the poms and recompile.

Comment: @Kiran yeah, I started doing that too (moving back a version). Looks like the blueprints-neo4j-graph code needs an update to work with to get it all working with Neo4J 2.0.0. I'm not well-versed enough in the codebase (yet?) to try my hand it patching it though...

Comment: @dafmetal : I tried that as well, but didn't run on any of the 2.X.X version. Please do let me know if you find a solution to this problem, I am not a Java developer, so I don't know if I can ever fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure if its really the answer for  my issue, but I tried to build it to target the 1.9.2 and put the jar files under the "plugins\gremlin1.5" and it works!!!  looks like this has issues to work on the 2.0.0 M06.

Answer (score 0):

As to your question if there is an example, I would say take a look at this [minimal example](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/sparql-plugin/) by Peter Neubauer, but it looks like that or something like it exactly what you are trying. Are you looking for some other kind of documentation?

As to your problem, the exception indicates that when the plugin processes the data you send it expects its json parser to produce something that can generate a `Map`, but instead the parser generates a `String`. Since you cannot cast a `String` to a `Map`, it throws a `ClassCastException`. The reason the json parser finds a `String` and not a `Map` is probably because you omit the braces `{}` that should begin and end your json payload to signify that it is a `JSONObject`, which in turn can be deserialised to a `Map`. Try adding the braces and see if that solves it.

**Edit:**
Your second exception indicates that the server plugin is missing a dependency on Blueprints. You can likely resolve this by obtaining a compatible version of `blueprints-neo4j-graph.jar` and putting it in a directory that is on the plugin's classpath. I think you'll need a 2.5 snapshot build to use with Neo4j 2.0.x, Google indicates you may find one [here](http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/repo/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blueprints-neo4j-graph/2.5.0-SNAPSHOT/).

**Edit:**
How were the tests failing? That's where you should start looking.

Your third exception indicates a version mismatch. If there were another missing dependency you would have more likely got another `NoClassDefFoundError`. With `NoSuchMethodError` the class loader is finding the class, but the class doesn't have the methods expected, so the called object must be an instance of a different version of a class than the calling object expects. You built it yourself with Maven? Then run

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

and look for conflicts.

I've never used the SPARQL plugin and won't for at least another few weeks, so I can only answer from the general to your particulars–you may want to consider whether you will get more attention posting a new question, stressing the Java class loading aspect rather than Neo4j & SPARQL plugin, or one tailored specifically to Neo4j & SPARQL plugin installation.

Comment: I did try with the {  } but in that case I got the following message "  "fullname" : "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.initSail(SPARQLPlugin.java:90)   "message" : "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph",
    "exception" : "ClassNotFoundException","

Comment: That's a different problem. If you want help with that you can edit this question with the full stack trace, or ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I have uploaded the stack trace in my initial post.

Comment: @Kiran, updated my answer for your second exception. Also this question may be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039995/neo4j-sparql-plugin-rest-usage

Comment: I tried it and now am one step closer, but looks like one more exception to be conquered before it works. Any idea what it could be this time? - Thanks Kiran

Answer (score 0):

There is an online fully tested example at http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/sparql-plugin/#_rest_api, which should get you started.

Comment: I am actually running the same very example, looks like some version mismatch issue. I have edited the post based on what I see now after following jjaderberg 's suggestions.

Comment: Any clue as to why I am get the last exception? I am not a java programmer so kind of lost in these exceptions. I understand from  jjaderberg that this might be an issue with some class not finding an method, but I don't understand which and how to resolve it. Any pointers will be of great help.